# Efficient sorting algorithm that puts elements of an array into two in either one of two sections according to some value

Tags: algorithm, sorting, split

I need some reference to some sorting algorithms/ideas that I could adapt to most efficiently split the elements of an array into two sections for instance, if e = 1E10-3
then I want all elements larger than that at the top of the array (They don't need to be sorted further, they just need to be at the top) and those who are smaller needs to be at the bottom.

So if the elements in the array was 0.0001, 0.0002 0.7 0.3 0.5 0.0005 then I'd like it sorted in the fastest way possible so that for instance it ends up at 0.7, 0.3, 0.5, 0.0001, ,0.0005, 0.0002

Comment: I agree with Ian Sellar below, that what you describe here is a single iteration (i.e. don't recurse) of the QuickSort algorithm with a given pivot value.

Answer (score 1):

It would be pretty easy to write yourself. Create an array of exactly the same size as the one you want to sort.

Pass through each element of the array you are sorting and put it in either the high side of the array or the low side depending on whether it is higher or lower than the pivot value.

You would have to keep track of where the last high side and low side elements are so you don't overwrite previous values.

Check out quicksort for a similar algorithm. http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort

Quicksort is not stable though which is something you are specifically looking for so make adjustments accordingly. You would only be doing the first step of Quicksort.